# How can I run iPhone app in Simulator without opening Xcode using command-line utility

Tags: iphone, ios, terminal, xcode

I know that there are some utilities which allows us to install iPhone apps to Simulator. But I found problems installing in this way when I have two Xcode versions installed on the system.

I want to set the environment variable for that utility. How can I set the private framework path for that utility?

https://github.com/Fingertips/ios-sim  : Link for the utility.

For more details please go through [my stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009472/does-any-one-have-used-ios-sim-utility-to-run-app-file-in-simulator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found the solution to this question and it is their in my StackOverFlow link.

OR

http://blog.abrahambarrera.me/2010/12/iphonesim.html

Thanks to Abraham Barrera.

Comment: Please summarize the link in your answer.